# How to find div that is not this id?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm using jQuery to select a `div` with a certain `id`, for example `id="style61150"` to `.slideDown()` the `div`.

I want to select all other `div`'s that do not have that `id` and slide them up.

Taking the value from a text field to decide what div to target `.slideDown()`.

```
productNum = $('#product-num').val();
$('#style'+productNum).slideDown();
```

I can't figure out how to not the second line in the code above in order to use `slideUp()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all divs with an `id` starting with `style` and substract the one you dont want to `slideUp()`, something like this:

```
$('div[id^=style]').not('#style'+productNum).slideUp();
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!

Final solution:
'$('#style'+productNum).slideDown(); 
$('div[id^=style]').not('#style'+productNum).slideUp();'

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has a [not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) that allows you to disallow certain selectors.

Try this:

```
$("div:not(#style" + productNum + ")").slideDown();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I get it, but targeting all elements with an ID that starts with `style`, and then excluding the one with the matched ID from the variable would be done like :

```
var productNum = $('#product-num').val(),
    elem = $('#style'+productNum).slideDown();

$('[id^="style"]').not(elem).slideUp();
```

Comment: .slideUp(), wouldn't it be?

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, I usually slide all elements up and then slide the appropriate element down.

Use a class to select all elements.
Use jQuery's `stop()` to stop the `slideUp` on the selected element.

Something like this:

```
$('.styles').slideUp();
$('#style'+productNum).stop(true,false).slideDown();
```